Text books in complex analysis
I want to know about a text for complex analysis which have all proofs of theorems using series concept and ideas.
I am not sure about my question is meaningfull or not
But In a workshop where I attand related to complex analysis, the resource person of the workshop mention that there are two types of texts are there for complex. One is completely in analytic approach like using limit and sequences and series ideas and anothor one is in algebraic appouch.
Please if anyone get my question  let me know about the texts

What is an algebraic approach? Any example?

I am not sure about that. But proofs are using only sequence and series concept , another book using only limits and continuity .

I recommend Visual Complex Analysis by Tristan Needham. This is a very approachable book that will give you intuition for the subject. There is naturally an emphasis from the beginning on power series, for example, understanding the trigonometric functions and exponential function as power series is very important. The proofs are mostly analytical.
It’s true that there are different approaches one can have, however I consider that the approaches themselves aren’t as interesting, as the way they relate to each other. This very visual book makes use of geometry and binds everything together in a great fashion.

I have tried teaching someone Complex analysis from the first time from this text and found it not fully adequate for "all proofs of theorems".

Thanks for your suggestion.

Textbook recommendations certainly have an element of personal taste attached to them, as well as comfort level with the topic. For example, a textbook which one would recommend to an undergraduate learning complex analysis for the first time would differ to a textbook one would recommend to a graduate student on the topic. I would therefore like to make a few recommendations - please feel free to pick and choose which ones best align with your personal taste and mathematical level!
For the beginner:
Complex Visual Analysis by Needham
This book is, in my opinion, the best book if you're looking to gain some intuition in complex analysis. Whether one would use it as the only resource depends on where you want to go with it - but I cannot recommend this enough for getting a sense of how the ideas in complex analysis can be visualised, which is a great skill as you progress.
Complex Variables and Applications by James Ward Brown and Ruel V. Churchill
This is a classic starter textbook, that is still very popular (with over nine editions published), which offers an approachable introduction to complex analysis with an emphasis on sequences, series, and analytic functions. It’s good for those new to the topic, but with a decent understanding of the fundamentals of mathematics.
Fundamentals of Complex Analysis by Edward B. Saff and Arthur D. Snider
This book provides a rigorous introduction to complex functions, limits, and integration. It emphasises the analytic viewpoint while offering clear examples and applications. It is perhaps a bit more advanced than the previous two suggestions, but is still accessible to undergraduates and perhaps self-learners.
For the intermediate:
Complex Analysis by Lars Ahlfors
A highly regarded text, considered a standard elementary text on functions of one complex variable, which delves deeply into analytic functions, Cauchy’s theorems, and singularities. This is a bit more abstract and assumes the reader is comfortable with basic real analysis. It seems appropriate for upper undergraduate level, to the beginning of graduate studies.
Complex Analysis: An Introduction to the Theory of Analytic Functions of One Complex Variable by John B. Conway
This book emphasises the analytic properties of complex functions and explores sequence spaces, function spaces, and analytic continuation. It’s more abstract than introductory texts but still highly accessible for motivated students. It is marketed for graduate students however, so I'd suggest having a strong background for this textbook.
For the advanced:
Complex Function Theory by Donald Sarason
A concise yet in-depth treatment of complex function theory with a strong emphasis on limits, sequences, and analytic continuation. It’s geared towards those with a strong analysis background, which is why I have grouped it in the more advanced category. Also, its bare-bones approach means one should feel comfortable supplementing this resource as necessary without needing guidance on this. It is suitable for graduates and researchers needing reference.
Real and Complex Analysis by Walter Rudin
Rudin's books are these notorious for being deemed difficult these days. In fact, they are scaresley recommended forward now for this reason. However, if one would like a comprehensive understanding of complex analysis, with the ability to come away after reading it with a sense of mastery and pride, then I suggest this one. The content is dense. The exercises are hard. The need for analysis is strong. However, for many it is a worthwhile journey, so one may want to consider it.

Thanks you for your suggestion
